# Getting typescript errors after the first `with` statement in ts-pattern

Tags: typescript

I'm struggglilg with understanding of how ts-pattern work.

I have defined the following type and an enum in TS

```
type ReducerActionProp<T, S> = {
  type: T,
  payload: S
}

export enum ReducerActionType {
  ADD = 'ADD',
  REMOVE = 'REMOVE',
  UPDATE = 'UPDATE',
}
```

Then, I have defined a function with the following signature

```
export const reducer = <T extends Maybe<WithId>>(
  state: T,
  action: ReducerActionProp<ReducerActionType, T>,
): T => ...
```

What I want from this function?
I want to return undefined if payload is nullish, or process the payload based on the value of `type` if otherwise.

The solution that came to my mind (and makes sense to me) is the following:

```
export const reducer = <T extends Maybe<WithId>>(
  state: T,
  action: ReducerActionProp<ReducerActionType, T>,
) => match(action)
  .returnType<T>() // tell the matcher we wanna receive T
  .with(
    { payload: P.nullish },
    () => {
      console.log('no paylaod')
      return state
    }
  )
  .with(
    { type: P.any }, // nullish payload is handled in the match statement above, no need to specify anything here
    ({ payload }) => ({
      ...state,
      ...entries(payload)
        .reduce<T>(
          (acc, [id, user]) => ({
            ...acc,
            [id]: {
              ...user,
              pending: 'true',
            },
          }), {} as T,
        ),
    }),
  )
  .exhaustive()
```

However, the solution provided above dosen't work.

1. The first error I'm facing says:

> TS2345: Argument of type () => T is not assignable to parameter of type
> (selections: Selections<WithDefault<ReducerActionProp<ReducerActionType, T> extends { payload: null | undefined; } ? { payload: null | undefined; } & object & ReducerActionProp<...> : "exclude" extends ([...] extends [...] ? "exclude" : "include") ? never : { ...; }, ReducerActionProp<...>>, { ...; }>, value: WithDe...
> Type T is not assignable to type PickReturnValue<T, T>
> Type Maybe is not assignable to type PickReturnValue<T, T>
> Type undefined is not assignable to type PickReturnValue<T, T

and it's about this function:

```
() => {
  console.log('no paylaod')
  return state
}
```

2. The second error is the following:

> TS2353: Object literal may only specify known properties, and type does not exist in type Matcher<never, unknown, any, any, unknown>

it doesn't like the following line: `{ type: P.any  }`

The solution below does work correctly, though I don't like it, because it seems that the point of `ts-pattern` is to match these things inside of a matcher, not inside the function body.

```
export const reducer = <T extends Maybe<WithId>>(
  state: T,
  action: ReducerActionProp<ReducerActionType, T>,
) => match(action)
  // .returnType<T>()
  .with(
    { type: P.any },
    ({ payload }) => (payload && {
      ...state,
      ...entries(payload)
        .reduce<T>(
          (acc, [id, user]) => ({
            ...acc,
            [id]: {
              ...user,
              pending: 'true',
            },
          }), {} as T,
        ),
    }),
  )
  .exhaustive()
```